# Xpath Contains with a variable

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, xpath

Been wracking my brain on this for some time, and cannot seem to figure it out.. I am looking to click on an email within my yahoo account. If I specify the values of the what I am looking for it works in finding on the first email. I need to be able to find any email based on the subject. 
This works to click the first subject if it contains  "POST/EDIT/DELETE: *2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE"

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'POST/EDIT/DELETE: *2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE')]"))).click();
```

If I make it a variable on the other hand it does not:

```
String emailtitle = "POST/EDIT/DELETE: "+ "*2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE";//Build email string
System.out.println("Email Title is: "+ emailtitle);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + emailtitle + "')]"))).click();
```

Where I am Searching:

```
<div class="subj" role="gridcell" id="yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1509685997190_1725"> <span dir="" class="subject " title="POST/EDIT/DELETE: *2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE ( cars &amp; trucks - by owner)" id="yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1509685997190_1724"> POST/EDIT/DELETE: *2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE ( cars &amp; trucks - by owner) </span>  <span class="thread-snippet" role="gridcell" dir="" id="yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1509685997190_1754"> IMPORTANT - FURTHER ACTION IS REQUIRED TO COMPLETE YOUR REQUEST !!! FOLLOW THE WEB ADDRESS BELOW TO: PUBLISH YOUR AD EDIT (OR CONFIRM AN EDIT TO) YOUR AD VERIFY YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS DELETE YOUR AD If not clickable, please copy and paste the address to your browser: THIS LINK IS A PASSWORD. DO NOT SHARE IT - anyone who has a copy of this link can edit or delete your posting. link PLEASE KEEP THIS EMAIL - you may need it to manage your posting! Your posting </span>  </div>
```

Ideally I would like to be able to have emailtitle change based on the title of the email. So using a variable is a must. But for some reason when I use it as a variable it doesn't return a value. Is there a reason this would be happening?

Comment: Your first code block has the text `POST/EDIT/DELETE:` twice, so that shouldn't have worked at all.

Comment: Yes, my requirement is to click on the email based on the title of the email.

Comment: Do not out emailtitle under double quote, since it is string, keep it without quote and check By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),emailtitle)]"))

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar That makes no sense. `emailtitle` is a Java local variable. The XPath engine doesn't have access to that.

Comment: @Andreas It should work. I think I have tried this earlier. Let him try this once By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),emailtitle)]"))

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar Seems like that is finding the element but its not clicking.

Comment: what exception you are getting?

Comment: @ShoaibAkhtar doing what you said is not giving an exception, it just doesn't click the title and open up the email.

Comment: @Kabone I have copied your HTML and try with HTML page. It identified element with your xpath. can you share your screen`s shot , so we can have more better idea.

Comment: @Sagar007 https://prnt.sc/h5lmmd

Comment: @Kabone wait for until element is clickable is not for div type element. Better to put condition to visible and then click.

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to keep the `String` **`emailtitle`** simple as :

   ```
   String emailtitle = "POST/EDIT/DELETE: *2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE";
   ```
2. Instead of :

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + emailtitle + "')]"))).click();
   ```

   You can try :

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[.='" + emailtitle + "']")));
   ```
3. `wait` will return the element if found. So take help of a `WebElement` and invoke `click()` in the next step.

   ```
   WebElement elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[.='" + emailtitle + "']")));
   elem.click();
   ```

Comment: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //*[.='POST/EDIT/DELETE: *2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE']

Comment: Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //div[.='POST/EDIT/DELETE: *2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE']

Comment: Because contains is must here

Comment: @Kabone Show me the definition of `wait`

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 8);

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried. Invoking click on the element. Same issue.

 
@ShoaibAkhtar idea of - By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),emailtitle)]")) doesn't throw an exception but it doesn't click the element even when I try 
WebElement elem = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),emailtitle)]")));

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
String emailtitle = "POST/EDIT/DELETE: "+ "*2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE";//Build email string
System.out.println("Email Title is: "+ emailtitle);   
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[text(),emailtitle]")));  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text(),emailtitle]")).click();
```

In case if you xpath return multiple elements then try to search your specific element based on index like

```
...By.xpath("
(//*[text(),emailtitle]")[1]).click()//try with different like 0,1,2
```

As you can see in below image, my xpath returned 7 matches, so via indexing I tried to get my specific element, then after using new xpath I can click on the element
[image]

Comment: Cannot locate an element using By.xpath: //*[.=emailtitle]

Comment: I tried looping through the found elements and clicking but still not finding it :(

I decided to try and get the text of each element i was looping through and managed to have one of the elements return - 

POST/EDIT/DELETE: *2007 NO DAMAGE TOYOTA CAMRY XLE ( cars & trucks - by owner) but it didnt select it.

Comment: As suggested by @sagar007 click when element is visible not when element is clickable as text is span in your case. I have updated my answer based on that. Please check, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to avoid constructing XPath expressions using string concatenation. At best, you can have debugging hassles like this one due to getting in a tangle with quotation marks, and performance problems because you are recompiling the expression every time you execute it. At worst, your code is open to injection attacks.

I'm not quite sure from the tags in your question what XPath API you are using, but most XPath APIs allow you to compile an expression containing a variable reference:

```
x = xpath.compile("//something[contains(@att, $value)]");
```

then supply a value for the parameter at execution time, something like:

```
y = x.load();
y.setParam("value", theValueIAmLookingFor)
y.evaluate();
```